# When factoring polynomials does not result in repeated factors

Tags: finite-fields, factoring

I found the following statement in the book [introduction to finite fields and their applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521460948):

> Let $x^n-1 = f_1(x)f_2(x)\dots f_m(x)$ be the decomposition of $x^n-1$ into monic irreducible factors over $\mathbb{F}_q$. If $\text{GCD}(n,q)=1$, then there are no repeated factors; i.e., polynomials $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m$ are all distinct.

Firstly, please indicate why this statement holds.

Secondly, are there similar theorems for polynomials other than $x^n-1$?

Comment: Repeated factors implies repeated roots in an extension field, implies common root with derivative, but derivative is $nx^{n-1}$, so....

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oh, I see it now. Thanks! Could you please write your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You don't need to know about roots (which requires field extensions, etc) to see that repeated factors mean $f(x),f'(x)$ have a common factor. Essentially, it just falls out from the product rule of the derivative...

Comment: Sadeq, the answer by @Thomas is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x)=g(x)^2h(x)$ then by the product rule of polynomial derivatives: $$f'(x)=2g(x)g'(x)h(x)+g(x)^2h'(x) =g(x)\left(2g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x)\right)$$

So when $f(x)$ has a repeated factor, $f'(x)$ has a common factor with $f(x)$.